# Nested List within Nested List- Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am a little bit new to python and I have this issue that I tried looking for the answer but I cannot seem to find it. Basically, I am using M-W.com's API to create a word dictionary and they have their data within nested lists. How would I be able to get the information from the nested lists? For example, in the list below in would want to get `"{bc}known or understood only by a small group of people {bc}{sx|esoteric||}"`, `"We have, however, tried to shy away from the super-scientific words—they're just too {wi}inside baseball{/wi} unless you're an actual distiller."`, etc.

I tried using an index, but the issue is, every word has a different index (i.e. just because it is located in index y in this word, doesn't mean it would be in the same index for another word). So I would need some sort of way to unwrap the list with different indexes (if that makes sense).

```py
[[['sense',
   {'dt': [['text',
            '{bc}known or understood only by a small group of people '
            '{bc}{sx|esoteric||} '],
           ['vis',
            [{'aq': {'auth': 'Gillian Flynn'},
              't': '"Nick, even I don\'t understand those clues," Go said. '
                   '"They\'re all {wi}inside baseball{/wi} between you and Amy '
                   '… "'},
             {'aq': {'auth': 'Deb Amien'},
              't': 'It might be a bit {wi}inside baseball{/wi} to some, but I '
                   'love it when crossword constructors poke fun at '
                   'puzzle-making conventions.'},
             {'aq': {'auth': 'Zach Johnston'},
              't': 'We have, however, tried to shy away from the '
                   "super-scientific words—they're just too {wi}inside "
                   "baseball{/wi} unless you're an actual distiller."},
             {'aq': {'auth': 'Dan McGowan'},
              't': 'This is very {wi}inside baseball{/wi}, but the House Rules '
                   'Committee meets today to consider a series of rule changes '
                   'for the 2021 and 2022 legislative sessions.'},
             {'aq': {'auth': 'Brandon Katz'},
              't': 'Earnings reports are always a bit dry and {wi}inside '
                   'baseball{/wi} for the casual entertainment industry '
                   'observer.'}]]]}]]]
```

Comment: Do you need to extract a text from `vis` list defined by specific author? By `Zach Johnston` in your case?

Comment: No not a specific author. Basically, "'{bc}known or understood only by a small group of people ' '{bc}{sx|esoteric||} '" at the top, and then all of the t's and its text.

Comment: In what form do you want to receive the extracted data? List of text, dict with list of text, etc?

Comment: A list form would be okay (all of the text in one list would work). Thanks for your help!

Comment: please use a more generalized example to make it easier to understand for other people

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[['sense', {'dt': [['text', '{bc}known or understood only by a small group of people {bc}{sx|esoteric||} '], ['vis', [{'t': '"Nick, even I don\'t understand those clues," Go said. "They\'re all {wi}inside baseball{/wi} between you and Amy … "', 'aq': {'auth': 'Gillian Flynn'}}, {'t': 'It might be a bit {wi}inside baseball{/wi} to some, but I love it when crossword constructors poke fun at puzzle-making conventions.', 'aq': {'auth': 'Deb Amien'}}, {'t': "We have, however, tried to shy away from the super-scientific words—they're just too {wi}inside baseball{/wi} unless you're an actual distiller.", 'aq': {'auth': 'Zach Johnston'}}, {'t': 'This is very {wi}inside baseball{/wi}, but the House Rules Committee meets today to consider a series of rule changes for the 2021 and 2022 legislative sessions.', 'aq': {'auth': 'Dan McGowan'}}, {'t': 'Earnings reports are always a bit dry and {wi}inside baseball{/wi} for the casual entertainment industry observer.', 'aq': {'auth': 'Brandon Katz'}}]]]}]]]

data_reduced = data[0][0][1]['dt']

// '{bc}known or understood only by a small group of people {bc}{sx|esoteric||} '
text = data_reduced[0][1]

// ['"Nick, even I don\'t understand those clues," Go said. "They\'re all {wi}inside baseball{/wi} between you and Amy … "', 'It might be a bit {wi}inside baseball{/wi} to some, but I love it when crossword constructors poke fun at puzzle-making conventions.', "We have, however, tried to shy away from the super-scientific words—they're just too {wi}inside baseball{/wi} unless you're an actual distiller.", 'This is very {wi}inside baseball{/wi}, but the House Rules Committee meets today to consider a series of rule changes for the 2021 and 2022 legislative sessions.', 'Earnings reports are always a bit dry and {wi}inside baseball{/wi} for the casual entertainment industry observer.']
vises = [d['t'] for d in data_reduced[1][1]]

text_n_vises = [text] + vises
```

Comment: Steve, is it what you need? If not, show one more example with another structure where the above mentioned code does not work.

Comment: Yes, somewhat. The issue is... the index for data_reduced is different for every word (i.e. if I were to run that I would get an index error for some words but other words it would work).

Comment: Okay, let me see if I can find one